# How to fix prepend method for certain width in pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html, media

I'm having difficulties with `prepend` method in my JS script, when resizing my webpage.

When I resize my web page I have changes in `DOM` I take one element and prepend it as a first child in DOM elements.

However, if I resize it more than `769` width, it does absolutely nothing, and it works only if I refresh the page. How to avoid this ? 
I have no idea how to fix this.

```
<div class=header__first-r>
  <div class="header__left"></div>
  <div class="header__center"></div>
  <div class="header__right"></div>
</div>
```

And her is JS:

```
function responsiveWindow(header) {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 481 && document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 768 ) {
        header = document.querySelector('.header__center');
        document.querySelector(".header__first-r").prepend(header);
    }
    else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 320 && document.documentElement.clientWidth<= 480 ) {
        console.log('min 320');
    }
    else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 769) {

    }

}
responsiveWindow();
```

Comment: Hmm..... your `else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 769) {` block is empty. Of course it does nothing. What did you expect?

Comment: This should / could be done with CSS and the `@media` query. For example `@media (max-width : 480px)`

Comment: @devius as you observed after prepend method my div with class of 'header__center' will be the first element in width 481 and 768px. It's empty because I tried to write event.stopPropagation(), but element stays first, I need to bring it back as a second element for other widths

Comment: So, why don't you do just that instead of not doing anything in your other condition blocks?